# Producing local complete intersection curves in singular surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $X$ be a smooth surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $C$ a local complete intersection curve in $X$. Does there exist a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ such that $C$ is a local complete intersection curve in $X \cup H$?

Comment: A "typical" curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is contained in no hyperplane.  If it is contained in a hyperplane, then it is called "linearly degenerate".  Otherwise it is "linearly nondegenerate".  (In some places, lines and conics are also considered to be "linearly nondegenerate" even though they are contained in a hyperplane.)

Comment: @JasonStarr: I might well be misreading your comment, but I'm not sure this is what the OP is asking. (They do not ask anywhere for $C$ to be contained in $H$.)

Comment: Oh, I thought it was an intersection, not a union.  But that makes the problem even easier.  For a Cartier divisor in a scheme, if the Cartier divisor is regular, then the ambient scheme is regular at every point of the Cartier divisor.  So at every point of intersection of $C$ with $H$, the union $X\cup H$ would need to be smooth, in particular (locally) irreducible.

Comment: @JasonStarr: perhaps I'm being really dense now, but why is C a Cartier divisor in X∪H? Say H is a hyperplane not containing C; near a point of C∩X∩H, a local regular function cutting out C would have to vanish on some curve in H. I am surely not following something...

Comment: @Artie: Chen asks for $C$ to be a local complete intersection inside $X\cup H$.  Perhaps we have different definitions of what that means.  For me, if I say that $A$ is a local complete intersection in $B$, then that means that the ideal sheaf of $A$ is everywhere locally generated by a regular sequence.  However, I agree that another interpretation is that $A$ should be *intrinsically* a local complete intersection scheme, and also $A$ should be inside $B$.  However, that interpretation leads to a *vacuous* question since $C$ is assumed LCI and contained in $X\cup H$.

Comment: @Jason: ok, my fault: I see that I just didn't understand the logic of your comment from yesterday. Now it's clear. Thanks!